# Are there cool Drupal tutorial sites?

Tags: drupal

I'm new to Drupal and I would like to know if there are some tutorial sites like:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/complete-websites/

http://net.tutsplus.com/

http://www.subcide.com/articles/

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are. Here are a few to help you get started:

Free:

http://drupal.org/documentation/customization/tutorials

Drupal Dojo: http://drupaldojo.com

[Lullabot](http://lullabot.com/ideas/videos)

[learnbythedrop](http://learnbythedrop.com)

[mogdesign - ultimate-drupal-tutorial-collection](http://mogdesign.eu/blog/ultimate-drupal-tutorial-collection)

Comment: Okay, then begin with the documentation link at the top of my list.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add more to the comment above. I also read http://drupal.org/planet daily. It has articles by some of the best programmers and shops in the Drupal world, though not categorized specifically as tutorials. If you haven't already, sign up for an account on Drupal dot org and then all of the resources on the website will be available to you.

Comment: I already made an account, have you already made something with drupal?

Comment: Yes I'm a designer, so worked with a development group on ipmglobal dot org where I'm Web Manager. I also have a DrupalGardens site (SAAS like wordpress.com) marilynsview dot com. I'm studying site building with Emma Jane Hogbin (sitebuildingextravaganza dot com) at the moment, and gearing up to learn more php.

Answer (score 2):

I have found http://tips.webdesign10.com/drupal-tutorials to have some useful tutorials although I haven't found as much tutorial support out there as some of the other cms's out there.